# IE6 list issue - First list on page ignores horizontal margins

Tags: list, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, margins

I am creating a store in Magento and have a weird issue with IE6 and the ordered lists on my page. For some reason, IE6 ignores the horizontal margin on my first list. Not the first element in the list but the whole list. I have multiple list on the page.

Here is a link to the offending page: http://byerofma.nexcess.net/products/pangean-furniture.html

I have tried everything I can think of.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Chuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without examining the code thoroughly I'd image it to be among one the various bugs IE6 has relating to floats and margins- you could try using padding instead, or floating the list differently?

Comment: So I ended up scrapping all the css and just rewrote it. Everything seems to work now and I never figured out why it was having problems...